# What is the maximum area of a rectangle circumscribing another rectangle?

Tags: optimization

The problem says that we have to find the maximum area of a rectangle that circumscribes another rectangle of sides $a$ and $b$.

Comment: What choices exist for the circumscribing rectangle?

Comment: The circumscribing rectangle must have one vertex od the original rectangle in each side of it

Answer (score 0):

**A solution based on trigonometry:**

Let $\alpha$ be the (smallest) angle formed by a side of the original rectangle and a side of the circumscribing rectangle. Then the area $A$ of the circumscribing rectangle is equal to the area $ab$ of the original rectangle plus the area of four right triangles, $a\sin\alpha\cdot a\cos\alpha + b\sin\alpha\cdot b\cos\alpha$. So
$$
A = ab + a^2\sin\alpha\cos\alpha + b^2\sin\alpha\cos\alpha
= ab + (a^2+b^2)\sin\alpha\cos\alpha
$$
$$
= ab + {1\over2}(a^2+b^2)\sin2\alpha.
\quad\mbox{(We used: } \ \sin2\alpha=2\sin\alpha\cos\alpha.)
$$
The area $A$ attains its maximum when $\sin2\alpha=1$, i.e. when $\alpha=45^\circ$, and we have
$$
A_\max = ab + {1\over2}(a^2+b^2) = {(a+b)^2\over2}.
$$

(It is easy to check that the circumscribing rectangle with area $A_\max$ is *a square* with side ${a+b\over\sqrt2}$.)